# Jboss comunity deployment tab not showing on eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

For some reason after I installed Jboss Tools on Kepler, the jboss is not showing the deployment tab.

Anyone knows if thats is a Jboss tools bug?

Comment: I have the latest kepler & jboss tools with an eap 6.1 and it is showing the deployment tab just fine. I recommend a re-install of both.

Comment: Which version of JBoss Tools did you install?

Comment: Version: 2.4.101.Final-v20131206-1843-B159

Comment: If I start a new workspace, It works fine, It must be something that get corrupted on my workspace

Comment: Yeah the plugin-oriented structure of Eclipse makes it a little unpredictable at times. I've never had this problem before though, its not like the deployment tab is anything JBoss Tools specific.